# julia lang - how to apply multiple functions to a value

Tags: function, dataframe, group-by, set, julia

I would like to apply a set of functions to a value and get a set of values as output. I see in `help?> groupby` (DataFrames package) we can do:

```
> df |> groupby(:a) |> [sum, length]

> df |> groupby([:a, :b]) |> [sum, length]
```

but can we do

```
> [sum, length](groupby([:a, :b]))
 MethodError: objects of type Array{Function,1} are not callable
 square brackets [] for indexing an Array.
 eval_user_input(::Any, ::Base.REPL.REPLBackend) at ./REPL.jl:64
    in macro expansion at ./REPL.jl:95 [inlined]
    in (::Base.REPL.##3#4{Base.REPL.REPLBackend})() at ./event.jl:68
```

or even

```
> [sum, length](1:5)
```

I would expect the output:

```
[15, 5]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes and no.** (i.e. yes it's possible, but no, not with that syntax):

---

**No:** The syntax you see with `|>` and dataframes is not general syntax. It's just how the `|>` method is defined for dataframes. See its definition in file `grouping.jl` (line 377) and you'll see it's just a wrapper to another function, and it's defined to either accept a function, or a vector of functions.

<sub>PS: Note that the generic `|>` which "pipes" an argument into a function, only expects 1-argument functions on the right hand side, and has very little to do with this particular "dataframe-overloaded" method.</sub>

---

**Yes:**
You can apply a set of functions to a set of inputs in other ways.
One simple way, e.g. would be via a list comprehension:

```
julia> a = [1 2 3;2 3 4];
julia> [f(a) for f in [sum, length, size]]
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 15     
  6     
   (2,3)
```

Or using `map`:

```
julia> map( (x) -> x(a), [sum, length, size])
```

etc.

---

<sub>**PS:** If you're keen to use `|>` to achieve this, clearly you could also do something like this:</sub>

```
julia> a |> (x) -> [sum(x), length(x), size(x)]
```

but presumably that defeats the purpose of what you're trying to do :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the source code. I could extend that to achieve: ```import Base.(|>)
(|>){T<:Function}(a::Array, fs::Vector{T}) = [f(a) for f in fs]
> 1:5 |> collect |> [sum, length]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 15
  5
```

Answer (score 2):

Your proposed syntax is possible in Julia by adding a method to the type `Array{T}` (here,  `T` is restricted to subtypes of `Function`):

```
julia> (a::Array{T}){T<:Function}(x) = [f(x) for f in a]

julia> [sin cos; exp sqrt](0)
2×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  1.0
 1.0  0.0
```

However, this has a large overhead if the number of functions is small. For maximum speed, one can use `Tuple`s and a `@generated` function to unroll the loop manually:

```
julia> @generated (t::NTuple{N, Function}){N}(x) = :($((:(t[$i](x)) for i in 1:N)...),)

julia> (cos, sin)(0)
(1.0,0.0)
```

Comment: That's an excellent answer. I will learn more about Julia's metaprogramming, http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/metaprogramming/

Answer (score 0):

`[data, data] .|> [sum, length]`

is also an option, elegant in terms of a minimal language construct, but sad due to repeating the data. Anyway, the `.|>` operator can be useful.

Comment: Can further simplify this by `Ref(data) .|> [sum, length]`. `Ref` prevents broadcasting over the data by treating it as a single element within a container.